# Why Maven complains incompatible types for Java lamda in specific case but other cases are fine?

Tags: java, maven

I try to compile my code and I get the error from maven:

```
Compilation failure
[ERROR] [...]AbstractPaneActor.java:[177,55] incompatible types: invalid method reference
[ERROR]     incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to com.anrisoftware.beyondimaging.gui.gui.actor.AbstractPaneActor.SetupUiErrorMessage
```

The code looks like:

```
    public Behavior<Message> start(Injector injector) {
        this.injector = injector;
        return Behaviors.receive(Message.class)//
                .onMessage(InitialStateMessage.class, this::onInitialState)//
       Error:   .onMessage(SetupUiErrorMessage.class, this::onSetupUiError)//
                .onMessage(GameTickMessage.class, this::onIgnore)//
                .onMessage(Message.class, this::stashOtherCommand)//
                .build();
    }
```

```
    private Behavior<Message> onSetupUiError(SetupUiErrorMessage m) {
```

```
    private static class SetupUiErrorMessage extends Message {

        public final Throwable cause;

    }
```

Why do I get this error? For all the other cases with `InitialStateMessage`, `GameTickMessage` and `Message` are fine.

Using maven-compiler-plugin version 3.10.1 source 17, target 17.

java -version                                                                                                                                                  openjdk version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.6+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

If somebody is curious I'm using https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/index.html Akka actor framework.

Error free compilation. It works also in Eclipse without any problems.

Edit: add example of `AppActor` that works fine in both the Eclipse compiler and Maven compiler:

```
    public Behavior<Message> start(Injector injector) {
        this.injector = injector;
        this.cacheResponseAdapter = context.messageAdapter(CacheResponseMessage.class, WrappedCacheResponse::new);
        this.assetsResponseAdapter = context.messageAdapter(AssetsResponseMessage.class, WrappedAssetsResponse::new);
        return Behaviors.receive(Message.class)//
                .onMessage(InitialStateMessage.class, this::onInitialState)//
                .onMessage(SetupErrorMessage.class, this::onSetupError)//
                .onMessage(Message.class, this::stashOtherCommand)//
                .build();
    }

    private Behavior<Message> stashOtherCommand(Message m) {
        log.debug("stashOtherCommand: {}", m);
        buffer.stash(m);
        return Behaviors.same();
    }

    private Behavior<Message> onSetupError(SetupErrorMessage m) {
        log.debug("onSetupError: {}", m);
        return Behaviors.stopped();
    }

    private Behavior<Message> onInitialState(InitialStateMessage m) {
        log.debug("onInitialState");
        actor.tell(new LoadTexturesMessage<>(assetsResponseAdapter, command.getAssetsDir()));
        return buffer.unstashAll(getInitialBehavior()//
                .build());
    }
```

Comment: I need a workaround like     private Behavior<Message> onSetupUiError(Object o) {
        var m = (SetupUiErrorMessage) o;
        log.error("onSetupUiError", m);
        throw m.cause;
    }

Comment: what makes you think maven is doing the complaining? Have you read the error message, btw?

Comment: What is the signature of `onInitialState`

Comment: @Stultuske it compiles and works fine in the Eclipse compiler, but if I do a mvn install then I get the error message. I guess it's more the maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: @Lesiak     private Behavior<Message> onInitialState(InitialStateMessage<T> m) {

btw, I use a lot of such classes and methods in my project. I add an example of AppActor that works absolutely fine.